# Spring FactoryBean as reference for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Creating a FactoryBeany for loading the properties from the Zookeeper.

```
public class ZkPropertiesFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<Properties> {..}
```

While using XML config it is possible to refer the bean as follows

```
<bean id="zkProperties" class="test.ZkPropertiesFactoryBean"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="zkProperties"/>
```

I'm trying to convert XML config to Java config, using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

```
    @Bean
    public  static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties() throws Exception {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prop = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        prop.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return prop;
    }
```

What is the equivalent of `properties-ref`? I'm not able to find any reference for doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`setProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setProperties-java.util.Properties-) of the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and set it by using your [AbstractFactoryBean.getObject()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AbstractFactoryBean.html#getObject--) method:

Your configuration could look something like:

```
   @Configuration
   public class ZookeeperConfig {

        @Autowired
        private ZkPropertiesFactoryBean zkPropertiesFactoryBean;

        @Bean
        public  static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties() throws Exception {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prop = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            prop.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
            prop.setProperties(zkPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject());
            return prop;
        }
    }
```